# Safari font kerning broken when wrapping letters into spans

Tags: css, fonts, safari, kerning, letter-spacing

I'm facing an issue with my font kerning.
I have a word where each letter is wrapped in a span element but on Safari the kerning of each letter is broken.
It works perfectly in every browser but Safari and I can't figure out why.

Here is a simple snippet:

```html
<h1>GOYAYA</h1> 
<h1> <span>G</span><span>O</span><span>Y</span><span>A</span><span>Y</span><span>A</span> </h1>
```

So the first `~ has the correct kerning for each letter with no problem but the second where each letter is wrapped with span then breaks:

On Safari:

[image: Safari]

On Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

And here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/leogenot/pen/jOQMYOE) just in case.

I tried all this CSS without any results:

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important; 
font-feature-settings: 'kern' !important; 
font-kerning: normal !important; 
font-smoothing: antialiased !important; 
backface-visibility: hidden !important;
```

And I have no idea why Safari would behave differently.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well. It's worse on some letters than others. (ie "n" looks fine, but "t" is shifted by a couple of pixels.